# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't see the HP scanner

Tags: drivers, hp, scanner, hplip

I have a HP 3630 all in one printer/scanner and it was working great on Ubuntu 16.04 with the HP Print manager. Now I did a clean and fresh install Ubuntu 18.04 and the printing work fine, but example Sane (or other scan software) can't find the device.

[image: error message]

I have installed `hplip` 3.18.4 that I found on the HP website, but still nothing. Even to add a printer in the HP manager didn't work.
In the WiFi I tried the WIFI-direct to connect with the printer and that works fine also, but the scan is not seen.

What to do to make scanning work on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I use simple scan to scan documents. Just run "sudo apt install simple-scan" without the quotes.

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Comment: The commands `hp-doctor` and `hp-setup` might give you more information what's wrong.

Comment: Your AiO should work, it is fully [supported by `hplip`](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index).

Comment: I agree the AiO should work, like he did on Ubuntu 19.04, but he doen't on Ububtu 18.04. 
I have tried simple scan also with the same result. No device founded.

Comment: Fresh install of hp lip 3.18.6, workaround form https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/485232 and today's Ubuntu update had solved my issue (I am not expert, do not know how it worked but now I can scan form my HP 1136 MFP)

Answer (score 9):

I have just finished a long install/uninstall session in order to solve similar scanning problem. I can not say this is the best approach but I can give a few points I hope this saves someone time.

- I have disabled cups auto adding of printers during this process, not sure this is important.
- I have installed an older version of HPLIP 3.17.11. Even if it says that is doesn't support Ubuntu 18.04, this version is working... at least for my printer.
- During installation, automatic is selected and I have opted out for HPLIP updates.
- After installation, I have installed `hp-plugin` with command

  ```
  hp-plugin -i
  ```
- Scanner at this point started working if I start `simple-scan` as a root.
- Need for that was fixed by executing

  ```
  chmod 755 /var/lib/hp
  ```

For me that was all.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, the older version solved my problem with Ubuntu 19.04. I had tried hplip-3.18.12 and today hplip-3.19.8 but never got the scanner running and the hp tools couldn't find the printer. After a few hours trying random stuff i installed hplip-3.17.11 and everything worked out of the box. No manual steps required like you have done after installing HPLIP.

Answer (score 3):

I had been using HP Deskjet 4535 MFP Scanning feature within Ubuntu 16.04. However after installing 18.04, it didn't worked, as mentioned by Tanama. (While I had fresh installed 18.04, my home directory was same as one I had used for 16.04.)

I verified that "hplip" package was installed during 18.04 stock installation, and tried simple-scan, sane-utils, hp-setup, hp-probe and so on. None of those attempts worked. Even Gimp -> Create -> xscanimage didn't helped.

Finally, following worked for me.

1. I installed hplip-gui package after going through this URL: https://websiteforstudents.com/installing-hp-printer-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-desktop/
2. Run Dash -> HPLIP Toolbox (HP Device Manager) and configured my device. I had used manual mode to detect device by explicitly providing static IP address I have assigned to my Wireless MFP. After that, use Actions tab within HP Device Manager, and select "Scan". It starts "simple-scan".

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue with Officejet 6700 All in One printer.
After installing HPLIP and running "sudo apt install hplip-gui", issues are solved. Printing, scanning and fax are supported.

Comment: Still works in 19.04.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add that I had exactly the same experience (18.04 does not rcognize scanner HP3630). I installed simple scan in a minute and it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Ubuntu 21.04 and Ubuntu 21.10:

1. Install these packages:

   ```
   sudo apt install hplip hplip-gui libsane-hpaio
   ```
2. Run `hp-setup`
3. Choose "Network/Ethernet/Wireless", click "Show Advanced Options", and tick "Manual Discovery". Enter the IP address of the printer. (I found it couldn't find the printer automatically, but did add it once I entered the correct IP address.)

   [image: Screenshot]
4. Click "Next" and finish the wizard.

It should now be possible to both print and scan.

Comment: I find it odd that `hp-setup` defaults to `SLP` "network discovery method" (at least on Ubuntu), as on a freshly installed 22.04 with stock `hplip` and `avahi-daemon`, my printer/scanner is found with `mDNS` but not `SLP`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `sni-qt`. I did that and the HP Manager starts to load. To install `sni-qt` run:

```
sudo apt install sni-qt
```

Comment: Thanks RMK, I did so. 

Now it works with a USB connection but doesn't work with WiFi. Also there are no errors now at start-up.
So half solved. 

I wish I could remove the USB cable and use the printer for printing and scanning through WiFi only.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an HP Officejet Pro 8600 Plus. After a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04, the printer worked fine, but the scanner could not be found. The solution was to use the HP toolbox and install the fax printer, which for whatever reason was not automatically installed at the same time as the main printer. All worked perfectly after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same thing happen.
1. Installed hp toolbox using the terminal.
2. Opened up hp toolbox and it automatically detected a missing driver and asked me if I wanted to download and install.
That worked like a charm; scanner now working.
I hope it is that easy for everyone!

Answer (score 0):

My HP 3630 scanner could not be found in any application (also not with `scanimage -L`) until I removed the HP 3630 printer from the regular system print settings (to which I had added it a couple of months ago) and re-added the printer as Network Printer -> HP DeskJet 3630 (1.2.3.4) -> Connection "HP Linux Imaging and Printing (HPLIP)".

Then suddenly `scanimage -L` showed:

```
device `hpaio:/net/DeskJet_3630_series?hostname=HPxxxxxxxx.local' is a Hewlett-Packard DeskJet_3630_series all-in-one
```

and scanning worked. I did not install any packages nor change any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

First delete ippusbxd:

```
sudo apt purge ippusbxd
```

Then install libusb-0.1-4:

```
sudo apt install libusb-0.1-4
```

Make sure that the scan resolution doesn't exceed 300 dpi.

Many thanks to Kellerkind_2009 from the German Ubuntu forum for this suggestion.

https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/hp-laserjet-mfp-m28a-drucken-funktioniert-sann/

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue with my all-in-one device from HP. For me the biggest trick to fix it was to lower the shields from AppArmor on one Python script:

```
sudo aa-disable /usr/share/hplip/plugin.py
```

Answer (score -1):

I got a similar problem (worked on Ubuntu 16 out of the box, but not on 18) with my Samsung SCX 3405W printer+scanner. I followed [these](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/KnowledgeBase/Troubleshooting/TroubleshootNetwork) instructions to troubleshoot the problem.

Installing the `snmp` package helped:

```
sudo apt install snmp
```

After this, the scanner started to work, but I still don't get an `snmpwalk` response from instruction.