# HPLIP can't detect printer

Tags: networking, printing, hplip, detect

I'm running the hp-setup which is part of the HPLIP utilities (I previously ran hplip).  I've got the printer plugged into the USB port and use the option for detecting via USB (I've tried doing it wirelessly but it fails too).  When it runs it produces this error output:

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.21.10)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Searching... (bus=usb, search=(None), desc=0)
Searching on USB bus...
error: Channel read error
error: Unable to read Marvell_EWS Channel
GET /IoMgmt/Adapters HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: hplip/3.0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0


error: Channel write error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog.py", line 274, in showNetworkPage
    adaptor_list = self.wifiObj.getWifiAdaptorID(self.dev)           
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/LedmWifi.py", line 127, in getWifiAdaptorID
    ret = getAdaptorList(dev)
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/LedmWifi.py", line 90, in getAdaptorList
    paramsList,code = readXmlTagDataFromURI(dev,URI,'<io:Adapters', '<io:Adapter>')
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/LedmWifi.py", line 531, in readXmlTagDataFromURI
    dev.writeMarvell_EWS(data)
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/device.py", line 2242, in writeMarvell_EWS
    return self.__writeChannel(self.openMarvell_EWS, data)
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/device.py", line 2272, in __writeChannel
    raise Error(ERROR_DEVICE_IO_ERROR)
base.g.Error: ('Device I/O error', 12)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog.py", line 719, in NextButton_clicked
    self.showNetworkPage()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog.py", line 276, in showNetworkPage
    self.showIOError(e)
  File "/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog.py", line 843, in showIOError
    FailureUI(self, self.__tr("<b>An I/O error occurred.</b><p>Please check the USB connection to your printer and try again.</p>(%s)" % str(e[0])))
TypeError: 'Error' object is not subscriptable
```

Background details:
Ubuntu 20.4 LTS
HP 551 Smart Tank printer.

The router software I have provides a limited list of what is connected to the WIFI and I don't see the printer in the list.  Other computers (Windows machines) are able to print and scan wirelessly, so I don't know how this is happening (do they communicate directly with the printer and not need the router? Or is my router software lying and the printer is probably on the network?).  After a bunch of failed attempts where the detection either errors out or just endlessly searches I find that the Ubuntu machine can print so I guess enough of the utility ran, but what I'm mainly interested in doing is scanning.  So without the HP software correctly setting up the printer I can't get to scanning functions of the software (HP scanning software says "no device connected")

Comment: there are some pointers in answers provided in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030926/ubuntu-18-04-doesnt-see-the-hp-scanner) which might be worth revisiting.